# Is there a way to make Splice effects cheaper?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there a way to make the Splice costs cheaper? For example, if I am splicing [Splicer's Skill](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSplicer%27s%5d%2b%5bSkill%5d) onto a spell, is there a way I can reduce the cost that I must pay?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because using Splice creates an additional cost, anything that reduces the normal cost of casting a spell can be used reduce the total cost.

For example, if you have 3 [Goblin Electromancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoblin%20Electromancer%5d)s in play, instant and sorcery spells cost you {3} less to play. You could play a [Shock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShock%5d) and reveal Splicer's Skill for the Splice ability. Your total cost would normally be {3}{R}{W}, but it would be reduced to {R}{W} by the Goblin Electromancers; you would not have to pay the other {3}.

> 702.46a Splice is a static ability that functions while a card is in your hand. “Splice onto [quality] [cost]” means “You may reveal this card from your hand as you cast a [quality] spell. If you do, that spell gains the text of this card’s rules text **and you pay [cost] as an additional cost to cast that spell.**” Paying a card’s splice cost follows the rules for paying additional costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2f–h.
>
> 601.2f The player determines the total cost of the spell. Usually this is just the mana cost. Some spells have additional or alternative costs. Some effects may increase or reduce the cost to pay, or may provide other alternative costs. Costs may include paying mana, tapping permanents, sacrificing permanents, discarding cards, and so on. **The total cost is the mana cost or alternative cost (as determined in rule 601.2b), plus all additional costs and cost increases, and minus all cost reductions.**

Note that only cost *reduction* will help; if you have something such as [Fires of Invention](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFires%20of%20Invention%5d) or anything that allows you to pay an *alternative* cost (not having to pay mana at all is an alternative cost); you will still have to pay the normal Splice cost, because additional costs are calculated after alternative costs.

Comment: Can I get the rulings for this? A friend is telling me it does not work in this sense.

Comment: @ShadowZ. Was just working on that. :)

Comment: @ShadowZ. What is the exact situation you ran into?  For example, you may be thinking of things like Omniscience or Fires of Invention as reducing costs to zero, but the rules treat those as alternative costs, so you'd still have to pay the splice cost with those out.

Comment: @CALEBF No situation had been ran into yet, I was figuring out if it was even possible to reduce the costs. I wanted to make a "Splice onto X" deck, but the keyword was just too hard to work with for my tastes. I wanted to find a way to make it more viable, and reducing the costs was the first thing that came to mind. My friend was telling me that there was no way to reduce the costs.

Comment: @ShadowZ. Oh, sounds good then.  Yes, definitely can reduce the total cost of a spell which includes additional costs.